# Did you mean in Elasticsearch not working with fuzzy matching?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, spell-checking, fuzzy-search

I am creating **Did you mean** feature for my site using elasticsearch. I have a field named "search_suggest" which has the mapping as below.

```
search_suggest: {
   type: "completion",
   analyzer: "simple",
   payloads: true,
   preserve_separators: false,
   preserve_position_increments: false,
   max_input_length: 50
}
```

and has

- **gionee p7**
- **gionee p4**
- **gionee mega 4**

  as values.

When I query for suggestion using the below query It is returning nothing.

```
{
    "spell_suggestion": {
        "text": "jionee",
        "completion": {
            "field": "search_suggest",
            "fuzzy": {
                "edit_distance": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is not returning any values as response.

But while querying the below one, it is returning results.

```
{
    "match": {
        "query": "jioonee",
        "fields": ["search_suggest"],
        "type": "phrase",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
    }
}
```

What is the issue? Am I missing something?

Comment: Quote from: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html. The completion suggester provides auto-complete/search-as-you-type functionality. This is a navigational feature to guide users to relevant results as they are typing, improving search precision. It is not meant for spell correction or did-you-mean functionality like the term or phrase suggesters.

Comment: Then, how to add the spellcheck feature in elasticsearch?

Comment: Quote from the page above: The completion suggester also supports fuzzy queries - this means, you can have a typo in your search and still get results back.

POST music/_search?pretty
{
    "suggest": {
        "song-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "nor",
            "completion" : {
                "field" : "suggest",
                "fuzzy" : {
                    "fuzziness" : 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}